# How do I send notification from SDK?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("MYSENDERID","FCM");
```

Hi I using the above to send notification from my Firebase to the apps using my SDK now it is removed in the latest version of FCM .Please help

Comment: ```FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnSuccessListener(token -> { // Todo });```

Comment: Where do i enter sender id , if i dont it gets token from default fcm account

Comment: You can't get the token of other users from FirebaseMessaging you need to store other users' tokens somewhere in an online database against their user ids which you can retrieve and send them a notification. You need to add another user token in your message payload and use this ```FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(payload);``` https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options.

Comment: @MalikBilal You can i was able to do it by adding com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0 manually and the using FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("SENDERID","FCM");